# Estimating the variance of a function of MLE

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood

Say I have the following likelihood :

$$
l(\alpha, \lambda) = n(\log \alpha + \log \lambda) + (\alpha -1 )\sum x_i - \lambda \sum x_i^\alpha
$$

which is that of **Weibull distribution**.

The question is,

> Estimate the variance of MLE of $(\mu, \sigma) = (-(\log\lambda) / \alpha,  1/\alpha)$

---

**Try**

I can estimate the MLE of $(\alpha, \lambda)$, $(\hat{\alpha}, \hat{\lambda})$, by solving

$$
\left(\frac{\partial l}{\partial \alpha}, \frac{\partial l}{\partial \lambda} \right) \overset{set}{=} (0,0)
$$

and I can estimate the variance, $\widehat{Var}(\hat{\alpha}, \hat{\lambda}) = I^{-1}(\hat{\alpha}, \hat{\lambda})$, i.e. plug-in estimator.

And by the **invariance property** of MLE, we have

$$
(\hat{\mu}, \hat{\sigma}) = \left(-(\log\hat{\lambda}) / \hat{\alpha},  1/\hat{\alpha} \right)
$$

But I'm stuck at finding $\widehat{Var}(\hat{\mu}, \hat{\sigma})$.

Comment: Can you show where you get stuck? Can you calculate $I$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your parameters of interest are non-linear functions of your estimates, I would suggest you apply the delta method. See [Hayashi, pp. 93-94](https://books.google.com/books?id=QyIW8WUIyzcC&pg=PA93).

Comment: You can calculate the hessian of the likelihood and invert it. the elements of that ( I think you have to divide it by  thesample size. check that )  will be the variance and the covariance estimates asymptotically.